# Tutorial for creating a podcast (in PHP)

Tags: php, xml, rss, itunes, podcast

I am looking for some tutorials for setting up a podcast in PHP. I have audio files and title/description data, I just want to make sure I get the XML part right so that it handles well in iTunes and other common players. (I don't subscribe to any podcasts, and I don't know what's popular.)

The title/description data is stored in a mysql database, and more files will be added each month.

I have created a basic XML feed which works fine in *my* web browsers, but I was hoping that someone could point me to some **instructions on making an RSS Feed properly, that is more likely to work in any program**.

I am already having issues with iTunes, which refuses to download the audio files simply because the `stream_audio.php` file in the url doesn't end in `.mp3`. I'm not sure if iTunes is being annoying, or if I have violated the official/unofficial guidelines for XML.

Comment: Why does PHP need to be involved? If the collection of files never changes, you just need to hand write (or use a tool to create) the feed XML. If the files do change, can you detail how the files and their associated metadata (titles, descriptions, etc) are stored?

Comment: are you using a CMS? if so you don't need to write any code; here is a snap of a properly-configured RSS feed that will generate XML that iTunes can read, if they can crawl it ok and you aren't violating copyright it should publish no prob; if you are writing php you are re-inventing the wheel and stopped doing that a while back; anyway http://tapper7.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/rssfeedxml.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, if you want a file to look like an mp3, you could do a simple Apache rewrite that internally rewrites the request, so convert http://blah.com/audio43657.mp3 (where the number is some sort of ID of what to stream):

```
RewriteRule audio([\d]+)\.mp3 streamingaudio.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

- [RSS 2.0 at Harvard Law](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) is reasonably digestible and outlines the required tags.
- Apple Podcasts Technical Specification - [Tracking Usage](http://www.apple.com/itunes/whatson/podcasts/specs.html#tracking) includes a small note on the "url must end in .mp3" issue, which [others](http://drupal.org/node/35398#comment-352353) have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

this class help ?
http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2809.html

Comment: `<lastBuildDate>1 May 2005 10:00:00 -0400</lastBuildDate>` hard coded? Seems like that could cause some errors with iTunes